# sorting in ruby by second field

Tags: ruby, sorting, matching

I like Ruby a lot but i can't do certain things i could in Perl, therefore please help

1. How can match one or another entry in line

   in perl :

   ```
   while ( <$HAN> ) {
     next unless /**$TAB_11|$TAB_35**/;
   ```

   in Ruby:

   ```
   f = File.open(li, "r:windows-1251")
   if f.each do |line|  
     next unless line.include? (tag_11 && tag_35)
   ```

   I tried or,||,and -none of them working like in Perl's case-how can I do this?
2. I'm trying to sort an array-but it doesn't sort properly-i need it sorted by second field-->date/time

   ```
   unless line.include? (tag_466 && tag_1004)   
   a=[]
   a.push "******************************** 1.Message Received On S Side ********************************",
    line,"\n" if line =~ /#{MAT_1}/   #li.console_blink, --to check source 
   a.push "******************************** 3.Message received ES side ********************************",
    line,"\n" if line =~ /#{MAT_3}/
   a.push "******************************** 4.Ticket has been created ********************************",
    line,"\n" if line =~ /#{MAT_4}/
   a.sort!
   puts a end`
   ```

   the results

   ```
   ******************************* 2.Message Processed On SGW side ********************************
   20120210 08:03:55,872 DEBUG IceTradeMessageMapper -  --------- Processing  Trade [1311883] --------- 

   ******************************** 1.Message Received On SGW Side ********************************
   20120210 08:04:05,404 DEBUG MQReceiver - Receive message "<FIXML><TrdCaptRpt RptID="763"
   ```

Comment: Your Perl and Ruby code samples are missing a `}` and `end` respectively. You should fix that.

Comment: You need to use two `include?`s joined by an or. Logically ORring together two (string?) values isn't how Ruby expressions work.

Comment: It's better to have the two questions in separate posts, not in the same post. That's because Stack Overflow works a bit differently to other forums.

Comment: If you're having trouble accessing your account, e-mail `team@stackoverflow.com`, please don't post follow up remarks as answers with another account, it breaks the Q&A process.

Answer (score 0):

Re 1. You can use a Perl-like regex match (`=~`).

```
next unless line =~ /regular expression|other expression/;
```

If you want to do it with `include?` it would be

```
next unless line.include?(tag_11) || line.include?(tag_35)
```

Re 2. I don't really get what you are asking here, but you probably want to look at [sort_by](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by).

Comment: great `unless line.include? (tag_466) or line.include?(tag_1004)` worked,

Comment: `next unless line =~ /tag_466|tag_1004/;` -that didn't work ....but thanks for the Perl offer thougth

Comment: As you can see second field(if it is second) is 08:03:55 ==>i would need to sort by that,or by 1.Message or 2.Message i added to line

Comment: What are `tag_466` etc, variables? If yes, it's `next next unless line =~ /#{tag_466}|#{tag_1004}/` so their contents get interpolated into the regex.

Comment: @TomasKlein Since you are new to SO, I want to point out that it's good etiquette to upvote and/or accept answers here.

Answer (score 0):

1) You can use [IO::foreach](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html#method-c-foreach) as a convenient iterator through a file, use [match operator](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html#method-i-3D-7E) to test regex pretty much like you would in perl.

```
IO.foreach(li) do |line|
  next unless line =~ /#{tag_11}|#{tag_35}/
  ...
end
```

2) You're using [Array#push](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-push) with three args: your long asterisk filled strings, the lexical var line, and the literal "\n".  It seems you intend this to be a triple to be considered as a single record. push will just append them to the array, perhaps you really want them to be a sub-array:

```
a.push [ '**** something ****', line, "\n" ]
```

Then you can sort by the second element with

```
a.sort_by! {|e| e[1] }
```

If you really did want one flat array, you could push as you did and use [Enumerable#each_slice](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice) to group into threes:

```
a.each_slice(3).sort_by{|e| e[1]}.flatten(1)
```

LATER: here's what I think you're asking for with the sort:

```
irb(main):001:0> a=[]
irb(main):002:0> a.push "** 1.mumble","20120210 08:04:05,404 DEBUG","\n"
irb(main):003:0> a.push "** 3.grumble","20120210 08:04:00,404 DEBUG","\n"
irb(main):004:0> a.push "** 2.mutter","20120210 08:03:05,404 DEBUG","\n"
=> ["** 1.mumble", "20120210 08:04:05,404 DEBUG", "\n", "** 3.grumble", "20120210 08:04:00,404 DEBUG", "\n", "** 2.mutter", "20120210 08:03:05,404 DEBUG", "\n"]

# sort by time stamp
irb(main):005:0> puts a.each_slice(3).sort_by { |label,ts,_| ts }.flatten(1)
** 2.mutter
20120210 08:03:05,404 DEBUG

** 3.grumble
20120210 08:04:00,404 DEBUG

** 1.mumble
20120210 08:04:05,404 DEBUG

# sort by integer value of first number in the label
irb(main):006:0> puts a.each_slice(3).sort_by{ |label,ts,_| label.match(/(\d+)/)[0].to_i }.flatten(1)
** 1.mumble
20120210 08:04:05,404 DEBUG

** 2.mutter
20120210 08:03:05,404 DEBUG

** 3.grumble
20120210 08:04:00,404 DEBUG
```

Comment: `a.push [ '**** something ****', line, "\n" ]` didn't work out -it duplicated the results and didn't sort them out

Comment: `a.each_slice(3).sort_by{|e| e[1]}.flatten(1)` -also failed see results below-seems to be complicated thing to do but it's gotta be the way `******************************** 6.C in Progress ********************************
    4e8 08:04:03.999 match TRACE   [23] 890
 ******************************** 8.SGW picks up the Message inserted by ES ********************************
    20120210 08:04:05,044 DEBUG IceAllocationIn] - Number of Legs: [1]

******************************** 2.Message Processed On SGW side ********************************
    20120210 08:03:55,872 DEBUG IceTradeMessag`

Comment: thanks for IO::foreach -->usefull module--i'll try it later-the reason  i didn't upvote Michael is the speed is important and i think we need to write efficiently or our scripting language won't make it,thanks for suggestions thougth--still trying to sort...

Comment: anybody ?any ideas how to sort?

Comment: @TomasKlein your question is still kinda muddled. Show us exactly your inputs and expected outputs and we can tell you how to sort.

Comment: `    a.push "******************************** 3.Message received ES side ********************************",
     line,"\n" if line =~ /#{MAT_3}/
    a.push "******************************** 4.Ticket has been created ********************************",
     line,"\n" if line =~ /#{MAT_4}/
    a.push "******************************** 6.Clearing in Progress ********************************",
    line,"\n" if line =~ /#{MAT_12}/; a.each_slice(3).sort_by{|e| e[1]}.flatten(1)
    puts a end  
    `Basically there should be several lines found per MAT var

Comment: `******************************* 2.Message Processed On SGW side ********************************
20120210 08:03:55,872 DEBUG IceTradeMessageMapper -  --------- Processing  Trade [1311883] --------- 

******************************** 1.Message Received On SGW Side ********************************
20120210 08:04:05,404 DEBUG MQReceiver - Receive message "<FIXML><TrdCaptRpt `  that the result -only has to be sorted depending on time and usually several lines would correspond to one *******2...*****.... message

Comment: @TomasKlein try again, but edit the code into your original question. I'm not going to try to make heads or tails of that stuff badly formatted in comments.

Comment: `files=Dir.open(Dir.pwd) files.each do |li| next unless File.file? li  f = File.open(li, "r:windows-1251") if f.each do |line| ; a=[]; a.push " 1.Message Received On SGW Side ", line,"\n" if line =~ /#{MAT_1}/ ;a.push "2.Message Processed On SGW side", line,"\n" if line =~ /#{MAT_2}/`-----sorry can't edit properly on mac--return goes to submit

Comment: `a[0]=["****************1************","20120210 08:04:05,404 DEBUG MQReceiver - Receive message "<FIXML>","\n"]`

Comment: `a[1]=["****************3************","20120210 08:04:00,404 DEBUG MQReceiver - Sent message "<FIXML>","\n"]`

Comment: `a[2]=["****************2************","20120210 08:03:05,404 DEBUG MQReceiver - Allocated message "<FIXML>","\n"]`

Comment: Now how to sort array a either by time or by steps 1,2,3-any ideas?

Comment: Sow how to sort this ?Any idea?

Comment: @TomasKlein see updated answer. Don't forget upvotes and accept if this solves your issue. In the future, don't try to paste a bunch of code into the comments, edit your original question to include nicely formatted code snippets.